# Placing dot product symbol slightly lower

Tags: packages, typography

I would like to replicate the placement of the dot product symbol in the following expression:
[image]

I need the dot product symbol to be of similar thickness, which I can manage to get with `\bigcdot`, though the symbol placement is in the "centre" (at the same level as the horizontal line of the + symbol). Is there a fix for this? I would like to keep the font package as `\mathptmx`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it, but I'd not recommend such an ambiguous notation.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathptmx}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\DeclareSymbolFont{boldface}{OT1}{ptm}{bx}{n}
\DeclareSymbolFontAlphabet{\mathbf}{boldface}
\DeclareMathSymbol{\wrongdot}{\mathord}{boldface}{`.}

\begin{document}

\[
(\mathbf{r}-\mathbf{i}-2\mathbf{j})\wrongdot(3\mathbf{i}+\mathbf{j}+\mathbf{k})=0.
\]

\end{document}
```

[image]

The name `\wrongdot` has been chosen at random.  Change it to your liking.

Comment: Well that happens to be the notation used in exam papers for the Cambridge int'l a levels (!)

Comment: @DarylHong It doesn’t make it good notation 